# 5 digit numbers from 1 3 3 0 0

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many 5 digit number positive integers can be made from the following numbers: $1,3,3,0,0$?

First I calculate all possible combinations $$\frac{5!}{2!2!}=30$$
Then I need to remove all 5 digit numbers startting with $0$ and $00$. They are not 5 digit numbers positive integers.

Starting with $00$ $$\frac{3!}{2!}=3$$
Starting with $0$ $$\frac{4!}{2!}=12$$
$12-3=9$, else I would remove numbers starting with $00$ double.

$30-3-9=18$

Is $18$ the correct answer, or where did i thought wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplest of terms (as a check), without using permutations and combinations:  You draw from the available choices randomly to calculate all combinations.

The first number is one of 3-choices (1, 3, or 3).
The second number is one of 4-choices (all that remain).
The third is one of the 3-that remains.
Then one of 2.
And finally, the last choice.

There are 4 different ways to arrange the number 13300 (first 3 first, second 3 first, and the same with the zeros in combination.

$$3\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 72$$

Then, to account for the double $0$s and double $3$s, divide by 2 twice.

$$\frac{72}{2\cdot 2} = 18$$

Answer (score 5):

Working from the other direction, the first digit is either $1$ or $3$, and then there are no restrictions on the remaining digits which can be permuted in $4!/2!/2!=6$ and $4!/2!=12$ ways respectively. Thus I arrive at $18$ ways, and you are correct.

Comment: The last digit has to be zero, isn't that a restriction? I can only write down 3 distinct numbers that start with 1 and 6 that start with 3. What am I missing?

Comment: @Vasya No, the _first_ digit _cannot_ be zero.

Comment: Oh, I thought the numbers have to be divisible by five in addition to being 5-digit numbers, sorry :)

Answer (score 5):

Another way to puzzle through:  There are $3$ ways to arrange the digits $1,3,3$.  Given one of these arrangements, say $313$ there are $3$ places to put two $0$'s:

$$3X1X3X$$

Think of each $X$ as a basket and now you have two zeros to put in the three baskets.  There are $3$ ways to put both zeros in one basket.  Then there are three ways to put the zeros in different baskets.  So for each of the three arrangements of non-zero digits, there are $6$ ways to toss in the zeros.  So $18$ is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would just compute the total permutations , and multiply it by the probabilty $\frac{3}{5}$ of starting with a non-zero

$\dfrac{5!}{2!2!}\cdot\dfrac35 = 18$